# Something wrong with my ttb_base switching

Tags: arm

First ,thanks for the good suggestion from artless noise.
I choose sharing 3G - 4G-1 kernel space address with usr task (vaddr : 0 - 4G) to switch tasks.
I think tasks switching would be like this :

> 1. a clock interrupt comes when usr task is running in its own address space
> 2. branch to the 3G of usr address space (also it is kernel 3G space).
> 3. context saving
> 4. schedule () 
>    {
>    ....
>    switch_ttb_base (ttb_base); 
>      // I think it is the key,(taskA --> TaskB)
>    // when ttb_base switched,address space is changed,
>    // it looks like TaskB is interrupted && arrives here.
>    // So,after context restored,it would return to TaskB
>    // which looks like TaskB is interrupted just now !
>    ....
>    }
> 5. context restoring
> 6. branch to new usr task

So,to share the kernel 3G address ,I should copy the page_tbls from kernel 3G address to usr page_tbls.
Here is my code, (ARM920T,S3C2440)

```
#define INIT_L1_BASE        (0x30100000)            /* 16K */
#define INIT_L2_BASE        (0x30104000)            /* 64k */

#define KERNEL_IMG_SIZE     (0x20000)           /* 128 K */  
#define KERNEL_CODE_START   (0xC0000000)        /* 3G start */

#define TTB_BASE            (0x30000000)          
#define PAGE_DIR            (TTB_BASE)          
#define TTB_FULL_SIZE       (0x4000)            /* 16K */   
#define PAGE_TABLE          (TTB_BASE+TTB_FULL_SIZE)                 

#define PAGE_DIR_SIZE       (0x4000)            /* 16k */
#define PAGE_TBL_SIZE       (0x10000)           /* 64K */

void copy_kernel_page_tbls (unsigned dest_ttb,unsigned vaddr,unsigned size)
{
    if ((size & 0xFFFFF) || (vaddr & 0xFFFFF))                            /* 1M alignment */
        panic ( "trying to copy page tables with non-1M alignment !\n" );
    volatile unsigned *_from_page_dir,*_to_page_dir;

    _from_page_dir = (volatile unsigned *)(TTB_BASE);
    _to_page_dir = (volatile unsigned *)dest_ttb;

    unsigned l1_idx;
    unsigned i = 0,j = 0,k = 0,page;
    volatile unsigned *_to_page_tbl,*_from_page_tbl;

    for (k = 0 ,size >>= 20 ; k < size ; k ++,vaddr += 0x100000 ) 
    {
        l1_idx = vaddr>>20;
        if ( !(_from_page_dir[l1_idx] & ~0x3FF)) 
            continue;
        if ( !(_to_page_dir[l1_idx] & ~0x3FF) ) {                       /* if dest page dir unit is empty */
            i = l1_idx & ~3;
            if ((_to_page_dir[i+0] & ~0x3FF) || (_to_page_dir[i+1] & ~0x3FF)
            ||  (_to_page_dir[i+2] & ~0x3FF) || (_to_page_dir[i+3] & ~0x3FF) )
            {
                panic ( "page dir corrupts with l1_idx %d !\n",l1_idx );
            }
            if (!(page = find_free_page ())) 
                panic ( "no more free page !\n" );                      /* alloc a page page dir*/
            wordset ((void*)page,AP_FAULT_ALL|CB|TTB1_SPG,0x1000);      /* set all be fault  */

            _to_page_dir[i+0] = (page + 0x000)|DOMAIN_SYS|TTB0_COARSE;  /* small page 1st 1KB */
            _to_page_dir[i+1] = (page + 0x400)|DOMAIN_SYS|TTB0_COARSE;  /* small page 2nd 1KB */
            _to_page_dir[i+2] = (page + 0x800)|DOMAIN_SYS|TTB0_COARSE;  /* small page 3rd 1KB */
            _to_page_dir[i+3] = (page + 0xC00)|DOMAIN_SYS|TTB0_COARSE;  /* small page 4th 1KB */
        }
        _from_page_tbl = (volatile unsigned*)(_from_page_dir[l1_idx] & ~(0x3FF));
        _to_page_tbl = (volatile unsigned*)(_to_page_dir[l1_idx] & ~(0x3FF));

        /* continue copying .... */
        for (j = 0 ; j < 256 ; j++ ) {                                  /* 256 * 4K */
            if (_from_page_tbl[j] & ~0xFFF) 
                _to_page_tbl[j] = _from_page_tbl[j];            /* FIXME : change attribute */
        }
    }
}
```

> **I call it like this**

```
copy_kernel_page_tbls (INIT_L1_BASE,KERNEL_CODE_START,1<<30);   /* 1G size */
```

> **the clock handler is**

```
extern unsigned long __ticks;

    #define __DEBUG__

    static   
    void schedlue ( void )
    {
        // ..............

        sync_dcaches ();
        invalidate_icaches ();
        invalidate_dcaches ();

        invalidate_tlbs();                                  
        set_ttb_base(current_p->ttb_base);                         
    }

    void __do_timer0 (void)
    {
            static unsigned i = 0;
            ++ i;
        current_p = task_st[i & 1];         /* just 2 tasks */
        __ticks ++;

        .....
        .....
        schedule ();
    }
```

**ARM just halt.I don't know why ? Any help appreciated !**

Comment: Not to answer your question, but the **ARM** has *domains* and *pid* registers for *fast context switching*.  You can use these features and avoid cache flushes.  Just a *domain* and *pid* register need to change per context switch.  Changing the `TTB_BASE` is pretty expensive.  Normally for a context switch, you just update a 2nd level table and flush that range.  With *domains* and *pids*, even this is not usually needed.  The OS and hardware mappings (high memory) remain the same for all processes.

Comment: Even shared library `text`, like *libc* can stay mapped across processes.  Having the *vaddr* for *libc* text map the same, mean smaller MMU updates and better cache effects across processes.

Comment: But FCSE can only use 32M.32M seems not so good to me.

Comment: Yes, FCSE is limited to 32M, but typically the main process is mapped in this range.  Shared libraries are at other location.  You don't need to flush caches or TLB, so performance is increased with FCSE.  The DACR or domains do not have this limitation; I believe there are only 16, but full 4G is supported.  You can combine FCSE with DACR to have a larger amount of processes.  Typical systems do not have hundreds of *active* processes.  Also, some of your updates may not be needed.  You can be lazy and leave them for a *fault* handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mmu test to test mmu cache operations

I switch ttb base with :

```
void change_ttb_base (unsigned ttb)
{
    sync_dcaches ();
    invalidate_icache ();
    invalidate_dcaches ();
    set_ttb_base (ttb);
    invalidate_tlbs ();
}
```

on my s3c2440 board ,0x30000000 - 0x34000000 is the sdram address,I do the test on sdram address space,
ttb_base switched successfully!

but when the code run at the high 3G address ,after I called change_ttb_base (),ARM just halt.I guess,the code running in high 3G address need MMU address translation,I changed ttb_base and invalidate all i & d cache and tlbs ,so ARM core don't know what the next step is ,so just halt .....

Is that right ???

Comment: I think you may still have issues with ordering.  After the first few invalidates, instructions are fetched to cache before `set_ttb_base()`.  It is hard to say, some things will depend on new vs old *ttb_base*.  Your question is hard to answer because it involves so many aspects of the ARM system.

Comment: Thanks ,may be I should read  source code from arm-linux and try more test ! 

thanks ^_^

Comment: Oh GOD  !!!!!.I switched the ttb_base without mapping port,then I used uart_printk () to write this port.Of course ARM will halt.......

How careless I am !!!!